# Infer data with SPARQL in Protege

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, protege

I'm trying to get my head around inferring RDF data. Say that I have these triples (RDF Turtle), which I created using Protege:

```
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

:hasSpouse rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ,
                    owl:SymmetricProperty ;
           rdfs:domain :People ;
           rdfs:range :People .

:People rdf:type owl:Class .

:Jane_Doe rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                   :People .

:John_Doe rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                   :People ;
          :hasSpouse :Jane_Doe .
```

The reasoner in Protege will kindly highlight the expected inference, that is `:Jane_Doe :hasSpouse :John_Doe`.

[image: Protege screenshot]

How can I see that inference with SPARQL? If I run this query in Protege (SPARQL tab):

```
SELECT ?subject
    WHERE {?subject hasSpouse ?object .}
```

It shows the asserted triple, not the inferred one. I understand how to do it manually, e.g. :

```
CONSTRUCT {?object ?prop ?subject }
    WHERE { ?prop rdf:type owl:SymmetricProperty .
            ?subject ?prop ?object .}
```

I'd see now the inferred data I'm expecting but 1) that would be losing the point imho (i.e; reinventing the wheel) 2) I cannot have 2 queries in this tab (construct, then select). There's got to be a way to do this automatically, just like the reasoner did.

I read in Stack Overflow a post saying to use 'Snap SPARQL' plugin in Protege. I tried but simple queries don't work (like the first one above). It's like it's a different language. How does it work?

So, how can I get the benefit of these owl properties with SPARQL? How can I have an OWL-aware SPARQL in Protege? Am I taking this the wrong way? What's the right way?

thanks for your help.
Nicolas

Comment: You have to enable and start a reasoner before you execute the query in the Snap SPARQL view. And I don't know why, but you forgot to define the prefix `:` in your Turtle sample. In any case, you should define your own namespace, otherwise it will be generated automatically on load. The query must be `SELECT *
    WHERE {?subject <http://www.semanticweb.org/owl/owlapi/turtle#hasSpouse> ?object }`

Comment: It worked. I guess I didn't enable the reasoner... Thanks a lot for your help, appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your inferences a part of your knowledge.

To do so, go to the **SWRL Tab** and click successively on the button

[image]

at the bottom of that Tab, start from the left to the right.

Comment: worked for me. Don't mix-up SQWRL with the SWRL tab, like I just did!