# Cannot infer statements with SPARQL Query in Protege

Tags: sparql, protege

I just don't figure out how to get inferred statements with SPARQL Query tool in Protege 5.5.0. It seems that it gets only asserted statements. The topic has been already put forward in
[Infer data with SPARQL in Protege](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54093044/infer-data-with-sparql-in-protege)
but I still don't get that right.
Could anyone help, please ???

Thanks a lot
Nikos

I tried the SWRL tab following the answer in [Infer data with SPARQL in Protege](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54093044/infer-data-with-sparql-in-protege) but it didn't help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a minimal example of your ontology and the query, and describe what you’ve tried.

Comment: Use the Snap SPARQL query view for inference being enabled. The standard SPARQL does **not** use any reasoner at all. And the SWRL tab is obviosuly not for SPARQL. It comes with an own query language based on SWRL + extensions, dubbed, SQWRL. That'S all you can do in Protege, for any inference beyond, use a triple store with reasoning capabilities, e.g. Jena, RDF4J, Stardog, GraphDB, ...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I have used Snap SPARQL query view and it works just fine but the problem is that I cannot query the transitive closure of a property. I will ask another question for that and provide a minimal ontology example.